Mac AppStore local receipt validation using StoreKit AppTransaction from Swift - async problems
EDIT: changed this question into an answer, for those needing a solution for old Objective-C apps.
Soon Apple will change the receipts for mac Apps to SHA-256 encoding, so if you like me still use SHA-1 to verify receipts you will be in trouble as of January 25 2025.
To just verify the receipt for the App after download, no in-app purchases, AppTransaction seems the way to go. Objective-C code below calls AppTransaction from Swift, returning an int.
Technote 3138 explains via Validating receipts on the device: "The receipt isn’t necessary if you use AppTransaction to validate the app download, or Transaction to validate in-app purchases".
Swift module:
import Foundation
import StoreKit

public final class ReceiptValidation : NSObject {
    
    private func ValidityOfAppStoreReceipt() async -> Int   {
        do {
            let verificationResult = try await AppTransaction.shared
            print("verificationResult=",verificationResult)

            switch verificationResult {
            case .verified(let appTransaction):
                // StoreKit verified that the user purchased this app and the properties in the AppTransaction instance. Add your code here.
                return 1;
            case .unverified(let appTransaction, let verificationError):
                // The app transaction didn't pass StoreKit's verification. Handle unverified app transaction information according to your business model. Add your code here.
                return 99;
            }
        }
        catch {
          // Handle errors.
            print("error.localizedDescription=", error.localizedDescription)
            return 99;
        }
    }
    
    
    @objc public func getValidityOfAppStoreReceipt() async throws -> Int   {

        let validity = await ValidityOfAppStoreReceipt();
                
        print("(swift) validity=", validity);
        return validity;
    }
    
}

Objective-c code:
- (void) ReceiptValidatedWith:(int)validation_code
// Called from completion block
{        
    if (validation_code != 1) {
        ALog(@"AppStore receipt invalid, exiting.");
        [NSApp terminate:self];
    }
    else {
        ALog(@"AppStore receipt VALID, continuing.");
    }
}

- (void) validateReceipt
// Validating receipt now only possible via Swift, call method AppTransaction.shared in swift module.
// As that all is async code we need to jump through some hoops to get at the value of the validity code.
{
    ALog(@"validating receipt...");
    
    // 'WithCompletionHandler' is automatically added
    [self.receiptValidation getValidityOfAppStoreReceiptWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger validation_code, NSError *error) {
        [self ReceiptValidatedWith:validation_code];  // called on completion of the Swift code
    }];
}   

.h
// AppStore receipt validation module (Swift)
@property (nonatomic,strong) ReceiptValidation *receiptValidation;  // swift

.m
@synthesize receiptValidation;  // swift module

// AppStore receipt validation with swift module
self.receiptValidation = [[ReceiptValidation alloc] init];


As your comment implies, don't use sleep. You have passed a completion handler, so you already have wrapped the asynchronous Swift code in something that will work with Objective C. Now you just have to handle it as you would any other asynchronous result in Objective C. It is a mistake to try and make it synchronous. Your UI needs to show some activity state and once you have the result you can update the UI and move on
